# Casimir Effect derivation for energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, momentum, casimir-effect

I was looking at the Casimir Effect, and I computed that $ka = n\pi$ where $k$ is the 4-momentum of the field and $a$ is the spacetime point where the scalar field becomes 0. Since $k$ is a 4-vector, this means that we can expand the expression $ka$ as $(Et - px)a = n\pi$. This would imply that $E = \frac{n\pi}{a}$ if the 3-momentum $p$ is 0, but in general this will not be the case. But when I'm reading references of the Casimir Effect, such as Tong's reference notes, he does not take $p$ to be equal to 0. My question is then, how can we say that $E = \frac{n\pi}{a}$ if the full equation is $(Et - px)a = n\pi$?

Comment: you're enforcing the boundary conditions at the plates which require you to decompose the phase space of the wave down into a sum of standing waves only.  The whole effect comes from "the phase space of the wave solution is quantized inside the plates, and not outside the plates"

Comment: > *"I computed that $ka = n\pi$ where $k$ is the 4-momentum of the field and $a$ is the spacetime point where the scalar field becomes 0."* -- Can you show your work? This makes little sense. Where are the indices? Why would total 4-momentum be limited by $n\pi$? What about volume where the field is considered?

Comment: @JánLalinský the field (when boundary conditions are imposed) is $a(k)\sin(ka)$ = 0, which implies that $ka$ = $n\pi$

Comment: If $ka$ means $ \Omega t - \mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x$ as you seem to suggest, then it is time-dependent and the  $\sin(\Omega t - \mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x) = 0$ is condition for events on a travelling harmonic wave nodal planes, not for a boundary condition. If you want to assume a static boundary in space where the scalar field $\phi$ is zero, then the boundary condition is on total field $\phi(boundary) = 0$. You can try to express this using Fourier series in spatial part. This does not lead to a condition like the one you're suggesting.

Comment: @JánLalinský I did the calculation again, and like you pointed out, I used a temporal boundary condition. By using a spatial boundary condition, I get $k_x a = n\pi$ which is what Tong gets when he uses the boundary condition for only one spatial dimension (x). Thanks

Comment: @Obama2020 indeed the boundary condition leads to conditions on spatial wave-vectors in the Fourier expansion. You're welcome.